# Object returns to the original position (after an animation) when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, keyboard, autolayout

I have this strange new issue: this code (that works perfectly)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        CGRect frame = _logoClaim.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= 180;
        _logoClaim.frame = frame;
    } completion:NULL];
```

moves a view that contains a UIImageView and an UILabel to the top of my self.view.

The view that moves unhides a UITextField.
When I try to write text into the UITextField, obviously appear the keyboard.
And at this moment, the view animated before, returns to the original start position!!!

What is the reason?

Comment: Not a day goes by that I don't see some version of this question. This is due to auto layout. If you set the frames of any objects you created in the storyboard or xib (with auto layout on), they will revert to their size and positions defined by their constraints whenever the view needs to be redrawn.

Comment: Yes I know. And I understood that I need to resolve without automation the problem... but I thought there might be an easier way.
Anyway... thanks a a lot. Only one thing: I hold your -1 but if you see every day this issue… don’t you think that is a question for a site like this? Or we need to post on masterchef site?!?!?
think about it. Have a nice day and excuse me for your time rdelmar :|

Comment: The way you should solve this is to make IBOutlets to any constraints you need to modify, any change their constant values in code, instead of setting frames.

Comment: Thank you. I think that Is an complex method for a complex UI.... 
but seems to be the only!!!

Comment: I don't know why you think that's complex. You need one IBOutlet, and 2 lines of code in your animation block.

Comment: :)) ok not complex but long? Could be more simply a call such as: _myView.holdLastPosition!!

Answer (score 1):

Put a completion block in your animation and check the finished value. The keyboard is cancelling the animation and the finished bool will be NO. I would disable input in the UITextField until the animation is completed. Do this in your completion block.

**EDIT** 
Looking at your duration and re-reading the question,I may be mistaken with what I think you mean. If this answer is incorrect I will remove it.

Also, search your code for _logoClaim.frame in case you are adjusting it onKeyboardWillAppear

Comment: Certainly solve in this way. It's only that I was looking for a short way! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create outlet for its bottom/top space constraints and update the constant value of it inside the animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
...
animations:^{
    /*Update the value of the constraint outlet supposing it to be a bottom space constraint*/
    _layoutConstraintBottom += 180;
    [self.logoClaim layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:NULL];
```

Do not forget to call -layoutIfNeeded for your animating view.